# Solve Set of Linear Equations (Analytic)

Tags: matrix

I have at a hand a set of linear equations of the form

M*x=y  (matrix form)
M_ij * x_j = y_i    where i = 1,...,N  (in components)

where M is symmetric, and all its elements are positive.
Further, all of y's elements equal 1.

I need the solution vector x as a function of M in the general case where N is some integer. I was hoping that calculating the inverse of M is avoidable due to the properties of M and y.

Is there a function in Mathematica to which I can explain this problem?
Or does somebody here even see the solution?

Thanks for your help!
Steffen

Comment: see [LinearSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearSolve.html) in the docs.

Comment: This seems more an algebra problem than a Mathematica problem. Try [the book of Lay](http://www.r-5.org/files/books/computers/algo-list/linear-algebra/David_Lay-Linear_Algebra_and_Its_Applications-EN.pdf)

Comment: e.g., `m = {{a, b, c}, {b, d, e}, {c, e, f}};
LinearSolve[m, ConstantArray[1, Length@m]]`?

Comment: You're right, of course. I realize this is an algebra problem, and was hoping that Mathematica might help solve it. I'm not aware of Mathematica functions to which I can explain a "general" symmetric matrix M of arbitrary size though. Is anyone?

Comment: Thanks! Now, I don't need the solution for a particular size or entries of the matrix, but for a general symmetric NxN-matrix. Can this be fed to LinearSolve?

Comment: @Steffen I think you might be asking for too much here this is more of a mathematics problem, or rather a request for creation of an algorithm, also, JJBK this is more of a comment, what you’ve posted. But, good on y’all for doing fun maths stuff! (I love this sorta stuff!) id look up some linear decomposition methods, maybe householder transformations would help you, additionally!

Comment: Try to construct the general matrix for us! :D

Comment: For what little it's worth, in the invertible case that rhs implies the result can be obtained as the total of the rows of the inverse matrix.

Answer (score 1):

an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix $M$:

```
M[n_Integer?Positive] := Array[m @@ Sort[{##}] &, {n, n}]
```

an $\vec{y}$-vector with only 1-elements:

```
y[n_Integer?Positive] := ConstantArray[1, n]
```

find the solution for any $n$:

```
x[n_Integer?Positive] := LinearSolve[M[n], y[n]]
```

test:

```
x[1]
```

> {1/m[1, 1]}

```
x[2]
```

> {(-m[1, 2] + m[2, 2])/(-m[1, 2]^2 + m[1, 1] m[2, 2]), (
>    m[1, 1] - m[1, 2])/(-m[1, 2]^2 + m[1, 1] m[2, 2])}

```
x[3]
```

> {(
>    m[1, 3] m[2, 2] - m[1, 2] m[2, 3] - m[1, 3] m[2, 3] + m[2, 3]^2 + 
>     m[1, 2] m[3, 3] - m[2, 2] m[3, 3])/(
>    m[1, 3]^2 m[2, 2] - 2 m[1, 2] m[1, 3] m[2, 3] + m[1, 1] m[2, 3]^2 + 
>     m[1, 2]^2 m[3, 3] - m[1, 1] m[2, 2] m[3, 3]), (
>    m[1, 2] m[1, 3] - m[1, 3]^2 - m[1, 1] m[2, 3] + m[1, 3] m[2, 3] + 
>     m[1, 1] m[3, 3] - m[1, 2] m[3, 3])/(-m[1, 3]^2 m[2, 2] + 
>     2 m[1, 2] m[1, 3] m[2, 3] - m[1, 1] m[2, 3]^2 - m[1, 2]^2 m[3, 3] + 
>     m[1, 1] m[2, 2] m[3, 3]), (
>    m[1, 2]^2 - m[1, 2] m[1, 3] - m[1, 1] m[2, 2] + m[1, 3] m[2, 2] + 
>     m[1, 1] m[2, 3] - m[1, 2] m[2, 3])/(
>    m[1, 3]^2 m[2, 2] - 2 m[1, 2] m[1, 3] m[2, 3] + m[1, 1] m[2, 3]^2 + 
>     m[1, 2]^2 m[3, 3] - m[1, 1] m[2, 2] m[3, 3])}

Notice that all the elements of the solution have the common denominator `Det[M[n]]`: we can simplify the solutions to, for example,

```
x[3]*Det[M[3]] // FullSimplify
```

> {(m[1, 2] - m[2, 3]) m[2, 3] + 
>     m[1, 3] (-m[2, 2] + m[2, 3]) + (-m[1, 2] + m[2, 2]) m[3, 3], 
>    m[1, 3] (m[1, 2] - m[1, 3] + m[2, 3]) - m[1, 2] m[3, 3] + 
>     m[1, 1] (-m[2, 3] + m[3, 3]), -m[1, 2]^2 - m[1, 3] m[2, 2] + 
>     m[1, 1] (m[2, 2] - m[2, 3]) + m[1, 2] (m[1, 3] + m[2, 3])}